OpenSearch - Searching for subdomain and domain
I am writing an OpenSearch query to match with subdomain and if not available then go for domain. Like first search with mail.example.com and if not available, then search for example.com
Below is the query I'm using, but it won't work if I search with multiple domains.
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "domain": "mail.example.com"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "domain": "example.com"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}


How to parse an URL
We use the uri_parts ingest processor
PUT _ingest/pipeline/url_parser
{
    "description" : "Parse an URL in the url field into the parsed_url field",
    "processors" : [
        {
            "uri_parts": {
                "field": "url",
                "target_field": "parsed_url"
            }
        }
    ]
}

Documents
PUT /test-index/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"url":"https://sub.hello-world.com/help/me/index.php?param=value#label"}
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{"url":"https://hello-world.com/help/me"}
{"create":{"_id":3}}
{"url":""}

Document with "_id":3 has no a correct URL
URLs are parsed by update_by_query with a prepared pipeline
POST /test-index/_update_by_query?pipeline=url_parser

One more update_by_query with new fields
POST /test-index/_update_by_query
{
    "script" : {
        "source": """
            String dot = '.';
            String fullDomain = ctx._source.parsed_url.domain;
            if (fullDomain == null) {
                return;
            }
            int lastDotIndex = fullDomain.lastIndexOf(dot);
            if (lastDotIndex < 1) {
                return
            }
            ctx._source.parsed_url.zone = fullDomain.substring(lastDotIndex + 1);
            int secondLastDotIndex = fullDomain.lastIndexOf(dot, lastDotIndex - 1);
            int rootDomainStartIndex = secondLastDotIndex + 1;
            ctx._source.parsed_url.root_domain = fullDomain.substring(rootDomainStartIndex, lastDotIndex);
            ctx._source.parsed_url.root_domain_with_zone = fullDomain.substring(rootDomainStartIndex);
            if (secondLastDotIndex != -1) {
                ctx._source.parsed_url.subdomain = fullDomain.substring(0, secondLastDotIndex);
            }
        """
    }
}

How to query a subdomain and if not available then go for a domain
I guess it is possible by two query
Only one query only could sort an URL with a subdomain before an URL with only domain
GET /test-index/_search?filter_path=hits.hits
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "exists": {
                        "field": "parsed_url.subdomain"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "filter": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "parsed_url.root_domain_with_zone.keyword": "hello-world.com"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

Response
{
    "hits" : {
        "hits" : [
            {
                "_index" : "test-index",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "1",
                "_score" : 1.0,
                "_source" : {
                    "parsed_url" : {
                        "path" : "/help/me/index.php",
                        "fragment" : "label",
                        "extension" : "php",
                        "original" : "https://sub.hello-world.com/help/me/index.php?param=value#label",
                        "scheme" : "https",
                        "zone" : "com",
                        "root_domain" : "hello-world",
                        "domain" : "sub.hello-world.com",
                        "query" : "param=value",
                        "subdomain" : "sub",
                        "root_domain_with_zone" : "hello-world.com"
                    },
                    "url" : "https://sub.hello-world.com/help/me/index.php?param=value#label"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index" : "test-index",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "2",
                "_score" : 0.0,
                "_source" : {
                    "parsed_url" : {
                        "path" : "/help/me",
                        "original" : "https://hello-world.com/help/me",
                        "scheme" : "https",
                        "zone" : "com",
                        "root_domain" : "hello-world",
                        "domain" : "hello-world.com",
                        "root_domain_with_zone" : "hello-world.com"
                    },
                    "url" : "https://hello-world.com/help/me"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

